# Get upload progress for YouTube direct upload?

Tags: java, upload, youtube-api, progress

I'm hoping there's an answer to this question now that it's been a while. I've seen [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395361/progress-bar-for-youtube-direct-uploads-with-data) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419451/retrieving-progress-of-direct-upload-using-youtube-gdata-api) questions here which haven't been answered, but they're a little older. Does anyone know of any way to get the progress of a direct upload using the [Java YouTube-API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java) in near-real-time? I'm writing a desktop application in java and being able to know whether I have 3 minutes or 3 hours left on an upload would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is apparently not yet supported. You can request this feature on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/youtube-api)... We'll see...